# Update text in WPF textbox user control using Winform

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, winforms

I'm using both `WinForm` and `WPF`. I'm trying to figure out how to update the text in my `WPF textbox control` in my `WinForm` application on button click. Using `WinForm` Textbox I can simply do `MyTextBox.Text = counter`, but with WPF I'm not able to. Why, and how do you do this?

For example, if i click on the button my WPF textbox should count up 1,2,3,4,5...but it doesn't.

WinForm Code

```
    int counter = 0;

    private void counter_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        CountTxtBx.Text = counter.ToString();
        CountTxtBx.Update();
        Console.WriteLine(counter);

    }
```

WPF User TextBox User Control

```
<UserControl x:Class="textbox_Update.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:textbox_Update"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="50
         " d:DesignWidth="239">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Text}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239" FontSize="20" Padding="0,7,0,0"/>

</Grid>
```

[image]

My WPF User Control Settings in WinForms

[image]

Comment: You have a strange Binding on the textbox named textBox. `Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Text}"`?

Comment: I just removed that. to its default which was `Text="TextBox"`, but it still doesn't work. I put `Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Text}"` because i thought i was missing that. I was trying to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind your textbox in the user control like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=CounterValue}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239" FontSize="20" Padding="0,7,0,0"/>
```

In code behind of the usercontrol you add a dependency property:

```
    public int CounterValue
    {
      get { return (int)GetValue(CounterValueProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CounterValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CounterValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CounterValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CounterValue", typeof(int), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(0));

  }
```

In your WinForm Button.Click event you can update like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  (CountTxBx.Child as UserControl1).CounterValue++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you i really appreciate it! :)